# how to find correct textbox from name?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 30 TextBox in my form. And i want to select correct one and write value there.

My textboxes names are :

tb_0_X, tb_0_Y,tb_1_X, tb_1_Y,tb_2_X, tb_2_Y, .... goes like this..

And i can create my textbox name :

```
string tbName = pointLoc.ToString();
string tbFirst = "tb_";
string tbLastX = "_X";
string tbLastY = "_Y";

string tbX = tbFirst + tbName + tbLastX;
string tbY = tbFirst + tbName + tbLastY;
```

Instead of writing all textbox such as :

```
tb_0_X.text = "";
tb_0_Y.text = "";
...
..
.
.
..
```

I want to write tbX or tbY but it is not possible to write ..

```
tbX.text = "someString";
```

how can i handle this issue ,?

EDIT :

To be more clearly ..

`string tbName` comes from **radioButton**. So i need to find which textbox i should change from tbX or tbY..

therefore i need to do something like `tbX.text = "someString"`;

Comment: I assume that you could create those textboxes in a loop. Storing them into a list at the same time can skip this step.

Comment: I dont want to create my textbox in function because it is already putted in form.

Comment: why don't you give more meaningful names to your textboxes?

Comment: I think, a form with 30 textboxes should be reconsidered, use something like a grid/listview.

Comment: @Selman22 they shows coordinates and i have more than 150 textbox and should i care their names  ?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at my answer for finding a textbox by its name. This is exactly what you are asking! How you calculate the name from your options is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string tbX = "textBox1"; // or whatever you want to call it
TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find(tbX, false).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    tb.Text = "Test";
}
```

The `this` keyword obviously represents the form the textbox is on.

Comment: Why the downvote? It answers the question. He didn't say he wanted to create a textbox, simply find it.

Comment: why tb comes null ? (it looks like what i need but tb comes null)

Comment: Because you could specify tbX as "fujihujdsjdhfjfd" and that wouldn't exist on your form. Then your program would crash as you would be trying to modify the member of a textbox that doesn't exist. It's a safety thing. It ensures that the result of the find isn't null.

Comment: You're welcome. I just wish I knew who downvoted this!

Comment: I wonder too also my question is not good ? I am sure that less people know that option..